# How to make single-spaced quotation in double-spaced document using grid package

Tags: grids

I am new user and learning. I am interested in grid layout using `grid.sty` and trying to get a simple two column, double-spaced document with single-spaced quotation.

I did baseline `fontsize=12pt` and `baseline=28.8pt` (twice the given option on grid package) but that caused quotation to be displayed as double-spaced. I tried to reset the environment quotation using quoting package, but I could not find the option to for `singlespacing`.

I tried `fontsize=12pt` and `baseline=14.4pt` as in grid manual, used `setspace` and `\doublespacing` at preamble, then alternatively gave `\par\singlespacing` before each environment like quotation and `gridenv`, and `\par\doublespacing` after. That apparently does the trick, but certainly NOT the correct way to achieve double-spaced document using `grid` package with single-spaced quotation. I have no problem with the `gridenv` behavior, but I really want the quotation to be single-spaced. How to properly achieve this?

The trial-and-error working example.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt,baseline=14.4pt]{grid}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm,left=40mm, right=25mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\section{Blah! Blah!}
\blindtext
\par\singlespacing
\begin{quotation}
\noindent This is direct, displayed quotation or verbatim word-to-word copy from referenced material, when I am too lazy to paraphrase. This is done when the words exceed 40 words or so, but \bfseries{I want this to be singlespaced}.
\end{quotation}
\par\doublespacing
\blindtext
\section{Another Blurb}
\blindtext
\par\singlespacing
\begin{gridenv}
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\sum^X_Y}{\prod'_C} = x'' + y^{2} + z_{i}^{n}\label{eq1}\\
\frac{\int^\sum}{\int_prod'} = x'' + y^{2} + z_{i}^{n}\label{eq2}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{gridenv}
\par\doublespacing
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: what is wrong with the way your MWE does it, when you say "certainly NOT the correct way"?

Comment: I do not know what is wrong with my MWE, really. I was thinking that there could be other, proper ways to achieve what my MWE does--especially if the document needs many verbatim referencing (hence the display quotation).

Comment: If you wish to use it often, then just define it this way:  `\newenvironment{myquote}
{\par\singlespacing\begin{quotation}}
{\end{quotation}\par\doublespacing}`

Comment: Yes, the plan is to use it often and it can be that simpler. That works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments, I noted to the OP that I saw nothing wrong with doing the way he/she had provided in their MWE.  The OP indicated the need to use the construct often.  I suggested that the construct that was provided could be encapsulated in its own environment, as I show below in the `myquote` environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt,baseline=14.4pt]{grid}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm,left=40mm, right=25mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newenvironment{myquote}
{\par\singlespacing\begin{quotation}}
{\end{quotation}\par\doublespacing}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\section{Blah! Blah!}
\blindtext
\begin{myquote}
\noindent This is direct, displayed quotation or verbatim word-to-word copy from referenced material, when I am too lazy to paraphrase. This is done when the words exceed 40 words or so, but \bfseries{I want this to be singlespaced}.
\end{myquote}
\blindtext
\section{Another Blurb}
\blindtext
\par\singlespacing
\begin{gridenv}
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\sum^X_Y}{\prod'_C} = x'' + y^{2} + z_{i}^{n}\label{eq1}\\
\frac{\int^\sum}{\int_prod'} = x'' + y^{2} + z_{i}^{n}\label{eq2}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{gridenv}
\par\doublespacing
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]